# Display number on draft invoice

Tags: odoo-11

In odoo standard the number of invocice is shown only when validating invoice.
Now I'd like to show the number also when creating invoice (draft invoice)

How can I do it?

Kind regards

Comment: You get the invoice number and date when the invoice is final. This is by design in Odoo. It is best business practice to have only one version of the final invoice so there cannot be misunderstandings about what version of the invoice was the actual invoice. Why do you need invoice numbers in draft state?

Comment: I'd like to print number on report invoice for state draft